# How to execute nested list first

Tags: python, recursion, nested

Suppose I have a list with nested lists and a function for "NOT" and "OR", like so:

```
def or_function(exp1, exp2):
    return exp1 or exp2

def not_function(exp): 
    return not exp

my_list = ["NOT", ["NOT", ["NOT", [False, "OR", ["NOT", False]]]]]
```

How do you execute the innermost list (`["NOT", False]`) first, then the second innermost (`[False, "OR", ["NOT", False]]`) etc. so that it in the end will return `False`? I understand that double recursion might be of some use here, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: instead of using ugly lists of lists you can go with some class with tree structure

Comment: @AzatIbrakov How is a nested list not a tree structure?

Comment: i'm not saying that lists of lists not a tree structure, i'm saying that it looks ugly, also lists supposed to have homogenous objects, for heterogenous we have tuples

Comment: @AzatIbrakov "lists supposed to have homogenous objects, for heterogenous we have tuples" Never heard that one before :)

Comment: @schwobaseggl "Tuples are for heterogeneous data, list are for homogeneous data. Tuples are *not* read-only lists." — [Guido van Rossum](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-March/033964.html)

Comment: @PM2Ring Interesting. The question then becomes: what is homegenous data? Must all elements be of the same type or must all elements work in a certain context?

Comment: @schwobaseggl The items of a homogeneous sequence must be of the same type. The current order of the data is incidental, i.e., the order can be changed (eg by sorting) without destroying the meaning of the data. In contrast, if you have a heterogenous sequence like (latitude, longitude, altitude), the position of each item in the sequence is integral to the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
def evaluate(exp):
    if isinstance(exp, bool):  # base case: atomic bools
        return exp
    # ["NOT", whatever]
    if len(exp) == 2 and exp[0] == "NOT":
        # evaluate whatever and negate it!
        return not_function(evaluate(exp[1]))
    if len(exp) == 3 and exp[1] == "OR":
        return or_function(evaluate(exp[0]), evaluate(exp[2]))
    raise ValueError('unknown structure')

>>> my_list = ["NOT", ["NOT", ["NOT", [False, "OR", ["NOT", False]]]]]
>>> evaluate(my_list)
False
```

Comment: Yeah it looks good. However I was looking for some general function that can do it with lists of different lengths and values etc.

Comment: You mean sth like `[True, "OR", False, "OR", True]`? The example you give only has the two cases specified in my solution. You would have to tell how to treat non-booleans, non-lists, and operator precedence...

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident you will only get input in this manner then you could try reversing the list

```
my_list = reverse(my_list)
```

this will make sure that the innermost list `["NOT", False]` is always run first, give than it is always at the end of the list